# Replace the id's with name using single query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT team_with.participant1,team_with.participant2,team_with.participant3 
 FROM event,team_with 
 WHERE team_with.for_event_no=event.event_no AND 
 event.event_no=4 AND 
 team_with.participant1=9 OR 
 team_with.participant2=9 OR 
 team_with.participant3=9;
```

I have written the particular query, and obtained the required id's in a row. I am not able to modify this query such that, in place of these id's, names connected to the id's are displayed.

The `student_detatil` table consists of `PK(sam_id)` and the attribute `name`.

IDs displayed by the present query are FKs connected to `student_detail.sam_id.`.

Comment: See normalisation. No other solution is worth consideration

Comment: OK, I will try that.

Comment: @Strawberry That would be a better solution if possible yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL JOIN to replace IDs with value from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431636/mysql-join-to-replace-ids-with-value-from-another-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a bad design to multiply columns storing different participants. Consider creating a separate row for each participant and storing them in a table. Your joining logic would also be easier.

Also, please use explicit `JOIN` syntax - it makes the query clearer and easier to understand by separating join logic with conditions for data retrieval.

Remember that operator `AND` has a precedence over `OR`, so that your `event.event_no = 4` does not apply to each participant condition. I believe this was a mistake, but you are the one to judge.

As to the query itself, you could apply `OR` conditions into join, or simply join the student_detail table thrice.

```
SELECT 
    s1.name,
    s2.name,
    s3.name
FROM 
    event e 
    INNER JOIN team_with t ON t.for_event_no = e.event_no
    LEFT JOIN student_detail s1 ON s1.sam_id = t.participant1
    LEFT JOIN student_detail s2 ON s2.sam_id = t.participant2
    LEFT JOIN student_detail s3 ON s3.sam_id = t.participant3
WHERE
    e.event_no = 4
    AND ( t.participant1=9 OR t.participant2=9 OR t.participant3=9 );
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Regarding the design, each event has different number of participants, it is not always 3. Therefore i had different columns stored for team members. Can you suggest something better?

Comment: You should have a table for participants in an event and store the column as a Foreign Key to point to your table. This way a various number of participants wouldn't multiply your columns with an event

Comment: But in that case, the number of tables would equal to no of events. Is it a good design to have so many number of tables? (i have 32 diferent events)

Comment: It wouldn't. One table for events, one for details about participants and one for participants in an event. I don't know your schema, but that seems to be a topic for a different question. You can post it here asking for some help on the design too.

Comment: My present schema has one table about student details, one for "participates in", one for event detail (as you suggested above). Now regarding the team for a particular participant in a particular event, i didnt want to create 30 different tables. Therefore i came up with one team_with table (max team size is 8 so 8 participant columns), one team_id, and one FK for_event_no to relate that team to a particular event.

Comment: This my friend is a topic for a different question. Post it and I may take a look at it. We don't solve complex problems in one question because that is an off topic.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the help though