# mysql replace ids with names from other table in query

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a table like

```
matches

match_id, home_team_id, away_team_id, home_team_player_1_id, home_team_player_2_id, ....
```

and I have tables

```
teams

team_id, team_name


players

player_id, player_name
```

Now I am trying to get the query the matches table with the actual names instead of ids.

```
query_result

match_id, home_team_name, away_team_name, home_team_player_1_name, ...
```

Is there a neat way to 'replace' ids with the lookup values from the tables?
The only way to do this that I can come up with is to join the teams table for each team and then the player name table for each player. Is there a better way to do this than writing 50 joins?

I dont want to alter the actual match table, just get the names in the query.

Comment: Join is the way to go. "Is there a better way to do this than writing 50 joins?" Do you have all the player_ids as columns in the matches table? That is not good, you should use a junction table for this relation.

Comment: thanks, Philipp. Yes, all player_ids are in the match table. let me read up on junction tables - no idea what that is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL JOIN to replace IDs with value from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431636/mysql-join-to-replace-ids-with-value-from-another-table)

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the tables 2 times each with a different alias something as

```
select
m.match_id,
t1.team_name as home_team_name,
t2.team_name as away_team_name,
p1.player_name as home_team_player_1_name
p2.player_name as home_team_player_2_name
from matches m
left join teams t1 on t1.team_id = m.home_team_id
left join teams t2 on t2.team_id = m.away_team_id
left join players p1 on p1.player_id = m.home_team_player_1_id
left join players p2 on p2.player_id = m.home_team_player_2_id
```