# how to replace ids with names in sql from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `passenger_count`

| pas1_id | pas2_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 2 |
| 14 | 37 | 4 |

that connects by `pas_id` with another table `passenger`:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bruce k |
| 2 | George L |
| 3 | Li Wo |
| 4 | Don Wa |

How to replace `pas1_id`, `pas2_id` with actual names from `passenger` table?

This self join query does not work:

```
select p.name,
  p2.name,
  count
from passenger p
on p.id = pas1_id -- and p.id = pas2_id
inner join passenger p2 on p2.id = pas2_id
where p.name < p2.name
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL JOIN to replace IDs with value from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431636/mysql-join-to-replace-ids-with-value-from-another-table)

Comment: @Strawberry please support my dupe closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join `passenger` to `passenger_count` twice.

```
SELECT p1.name,
       p2.name,
       pc.count
       FROM passenger_count pc
            INNER JOIN passenger p1
                       ON p1.pas_id = pc.pas1_id
            INNER JOIN passenger p2
                       ON p2.pas_id = pc.pas2_id;
```

Comment: thx, initially that's what i did but it did not work, the full problem is here https://sql-academy.org/en/trainer/tasks/64, my logic is this: self join pass_in_trip by trip field , then find those ids that are not the same, but still.. no luck

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p1.name,
  p2.name,
  pc.count
FROM passenger_count AS pc
JOIN passenger AS p1 ON pc.pas1_id = p1.id
JOIN passenger AS p2 ON pc.pas2_id = p2.id
```